# ordering by child's value in one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**posts table**

```
int id
```

**comments table**

```
int id
int post_id
datetime created_at
```

i need to order posts by post's comments created_at. I tried something like that but i can't select distinct post ids.Any help will be appreciated.

```
Post.all(:joins => :comments, :order => 'comments.created_at')
```

I want to see the post which was commented lately at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are passing is invalid.
The easiest way you can accomplish what you are trying to do, is by adding a column to your posts table - say `last_commented_at`. 
In your `Comment` model you add a callback

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  after_save :update_posts_last_commented_attribute

  def update_posts_last_commented_attribute
    post.update_attribute(:last_commented_at, updated_at)
  end
end
```

Then you can load your Posts by calling

```
Post.order("last_commented_at DESC" )
```

to show the posts first, that have recently been commented.